# Non-vim user mode

Tags: key-bindings

When I'm working in vim and someone comes over to help/write some code into the editor and they don't know vim, they get totally stuck and  we have to switch to a different editor.

Does anyone know if there is a plugin that turns off modes/vim specific things, so that they can edit like in a basic graphical editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Start vim with `evim` (or `vim -y`). This puts vim in "easy" mode: it sets `'insertmode'` and behaves like a point-and-click editor (from the docs).
2. `:source $VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim`—basically the same. Note that it sets up mappings (`:help evim-keys`).

You might be able to find or write a script to undo this whole thing, but it may also be easier to quit and restart after doing this. Sessions (such as via tpope/Obsession) make this less painful than it sounds.

Comment: Great answer! Quicker shortcut to #2 is `:ru evim.vim`, as using the `:runtime` command will search for the script file in `$VIMRUNTIME`. Probably worth mentioning the very important `CTRL-L` keystroke to escape to Normal mode in evim. It's mentioned in help but not very prominently. The more usual `CTRL-O` is also pretty useful.

Comment: @filbranden the only issue with `:runtime` is that someone might have other `evim.vim` scripts laying around! I prefer to be explicit, but that is certainly an option.